# Catesian product without duplicate pairs in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes for which I want to create a cartesian product.

When I do this, as expected I get matching pairs in the sense that I consider laptop and radio = radio and laptop.

```
 #2 dataframes to produce the cartesian product 
 SaleItems<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"))
 SaleItems2<-data.frame(Appliance2=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"))

 #create cartesian product
 SaleItems3<-merge(SaleItems,SaleItems2)
```

What I want is to get rid of the matching pairs, so for example the combination of radio and laptop only appears once.

Does anyone have any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Note that generally `merge` does not create a cartesian product but "only" differnt kinds of joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cartesian joins with `merge` pass NULL into *by* argument:

```
merge(SaleItems, SaleItems2, by=NULL)
```

Then to remove equivalent matches and reverse duplicates, extend it with `subset`:

```
subset(merge(SaleItems, SaleItems2, by=NULL),
       Appliance <= Appliance2)
```

And if fields are factors:

```
subset(merge(SaleItems, SaleItems2, by=NULL),
       as.character(Appliance) <= as.character(Appliance2))

#    Appliance Appliance2
# 1      Radio      Radio
# 2     Laptop      Radio
# 4     Fridge      Radio
# 6     Laptop     Laptop
# 8     Fridge     Laptop
# 9      Radio         TV
# 10    Laptop         TV
# 11        TV         TV
# 12    Fridge         TV
# 16    Fridge     Fridge
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to rearrange the column values in each row alphabettically using `pmin`/`pmax` and select only `distinct` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

SaleItems3 %>%
  mutate(app = pmin(Appliance, Appliance2), app1 = pmax(Appliance, Appliance2)) %>%
  dplyr::select(app, app1) %>%
  distinct()

#      app   app1
#1   Radio  Radio
#2  Laptop  Radio
#3   Radio     TV
#4  Fridge  Radio
#5  Laptop Laptop
#6  Laptop     TV
#7  Fridge Laptop
#8      TV     TV
#9  Fridge     TV
#10 Fridge Fridge
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way in base `R` which also excludes same-same matches.

```
f <- outer(SaleItems$Appliance, SaleItems2$Appliance2 , FUN = "paste", sep = ",")
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(f[upper.tri(f)], ",")))

      V1     V2
1  Radio Laptop
2  Radio     TV
3 Laptop     TV
4  Radio Fridge
5 Laptop Fridge
6     TV Fridge
```

**EDIT**:To include same-same matches do:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(f[upper.tri(f, diag = T)], ",")))

       V1     V2
1   Radio  Radio
2   Radio Laptop
3  Laptop Laptop
4   Radio     TV
5  Laptop     TV
6      TV     TV
7   Radio Fridge
8  Laptop Fridge
9      TV Fridge
10 Fridge Fridge
```